# Cannot Fast Forward/ Rewind mp3 audio files in Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to open mp3 audio files in chrome  using .Net framework 4.6.1.

here is my code in **View** and **Controller** respectively.

View

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <button type="button" onclick="PlayVoiceFile()">click</button>
</div> 
<script>
    function PlayVoiceFile() {
        window.open('/Home/PlayFile?path=' + 'C:\\blahblahblah\\Audio\\TestSampleMP3.mp3');
    }
</script>
```

HomeController

```
public ActionResult PlayFile(string path = "")
{
      return MediaFile(path);
}

private ActionResult MediaFile(string path = "")
{
      var byteWave = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
      return File(byteWave, "audio/mp3");
}
```

Everything is working as I expect it to be so far except that I can't fast forward or rewind the file. whenever I try to click on a progress bar to skip to a particular part of the file ,nothing happens. The progress bar doesn't seem to work.Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should do the magic. enableRangeProcessing is the key parameter.

```
    public ActionResult PlayFile(string path = "")
    {
        return PhysicalFile(path, "audio/mp3", enableRangeProcessing: true);
    }
```

Comment: are there  any alternatives to enableRangeProcessing ? since I'm not using asp.net core, I can't  apply this property.